# System of inequalities - proving $n=k$

Tags: inequality

Let's say we have the following inequalities:

$$n < x+1 \le k + 1$$ and $$k < x+1 \le n+1$$

How to prove that $n=k$?

Comment: if there is no other conditions, you can't say anything of $k,n$, it can be$k>n,k<n,k=n$

Answer (score 0):

From the inequalities you can deduce that

$$k<x+1\leq k+1$$
$$n<x+1\leq n+1$$

Since each set of $\mathbb{N}$ has exactly one minimun you can conclude that $n=k$ because $n$ and $k$ are two number satisfying a minimun propierty.

Answer (score 0):

$n<k+1$ and $k+1<n+2$, from the first two formulas. So $n<k+1<n+2$.

Presumably $n$ and $k$ are integers (I will assume that). Since there is only the integral $n+1$ between $n$ and $n+2$, you get $n+1=k+1$ and $n=k$.

Answer (score 0):

The statements $$n < x+1 \le k + 1$$ and $$k < x+1 \le n+1$$ mean 
$n < x+1$ **and** $x+1 \le k + 1$ **and** $k < x+1 $ **and** $x+1\le n+1$.

So we have $$n < x+1 \le n + 1$$ and $$k < x+1 \le k+1.$$
That is, the largest integer less than $x+1$ is $n$ and that same integer is $k$.  Therefore $n=k$.